# HTML5 Header markup and SEO / absolute position

Tags: html, header

i would like to put my header and my nav (with html5 markup) in the bottom of my site with

`absolute position (top:10px}`

Is it valid (ie have a header in the bottom of my site after the footer ?)

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->

<body>
<aside></aside>
<div id="main" role="main"></div>
<aside></aside>
<footer></footer>
<nav>link1 link2</nav>  <--- absolute position top : 150px
<header>                <--- absolute position top : 50px
<h1>Blabla</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: If you're going to absolute position it, why do you want the `header` at the end of your markup? Just curious

Comment: it s for SEO. The first contant that appears to the robots is my main div with the interesting content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a technical point of view the code will validate as HTML5.

However, one of the main aims of HTML5 is to improve the semantics of code. Which is why new elements were brought in to have more meaning.

So from a semantic point of view this is really not the best way to go about it. Best practice is that the html should flow in the order of content from top to bottom. If the footer is not being used as a footer then it would be better to use a general container such as a `div`. However if it is being used as the main footer for the page it should really be at the end of your document.

I would point out though, that you can use more than one `header` and `footer` element in a page.

Answer (score 2):

According to the HTML 5 Specification, the body element's content model is simply Flow Content.

See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element

Flow content can contain header elements and footer elements.  The order is not specified.

You are good.

BTW I was able to successfully validate, as HTML 5 a document with the header after a footer at http://validator.w3.org/check.  So if the W3C says it is okay, I would say you are good to go.

Comment: the W3C says don't show me errors or warnings with the header in the bottom of the page..
thx Ray

Comment: It very well may be valid, but it is really not the appropriate method. But, if you do go ahead with this method, be sure to thoroughly check compatibility among various browsers.

Comment: Can you clarify not-appropriate?  The designers of HTML5 could have chosen to require headers to come before footers, but they did not.  They did however, force dts to come before dds within a dl.  Since they specifically allowed elements within bodies to be unordered, the OP can use this fact.  By "not appropriate" do you mean "not a best practice"? I agree the footer-before-header might read funny.  But I would hope browsers would follow the standard.  IE has now joined the club! :-)